# Stack operation in c using functions

Tags: c, function, stack

In this program the pop function is not getting executed.

The statement 'Popped value' is not printed in output.

When I display stack then all the elements I have pushed are printed, even after pop function is called.

I need to know why is this happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 7

int x,st[MAX],i,top=-1;

// Entering the elements into stack
void push()
 {
     if(top>=MAX)
        printf("Stack overflow\n");
      else
      {
        printf("\nEnter element to be pushed: ");
        scanf("%d",&x);
        top++;
        st[top]=x;
      }
 }

//Deleting an element from the stack 
int pop()
 {
    if(top==-1)
       printf("Stack is empty");
    else
    {
      x=st[top];
      top--;
      return(x); 
    }

  }

//Displaying contents of stack
void display()
 {

   if(top<=-1)
    printf("Stack Empty");
   else
   {      
       printf("Stack contents\n");
       for(i=top;i>=0;i--)
       printf("%d\n",st[i]);
   }
} 

int main()
{
    int c,item;
    char ch='y';
    while(ch=='y')
    {
      printf("Enter choice\t");
      printf("1.Push 2.Pop 3.Display 4.Exit \n");
      scanf("%d",&c);
      switch(c)
      {
       case 1:
        push();
         break;
       case2:
         item=pop();
         printf("Popped value %d",item);
         break;
       case 3:
         display();
         break;
       case 4:
         exit(0);
         break; 
       }
     }
    getch();
 }
```

Comment: Change `case2:` to `case 2:`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: Beware !!! In case `top` is -1, you'll `return` **nothing** and essentially invoke UB.... Please enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way(in your coding-style) to write the the `pop` function is as below:

```
#include <exception>
//Deleting an element from the stack
int pop()
{
    if(top == -1)
       throw exception("Stack is empty");
    else
      return st[top--];
}
```

In this case if the stack is *empty* an [exception](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) will raise **and nothing will return**, but as you have wrote after `printf` you must return something in your if statement which you didn't!!

And also you have a typo in your `case2` which should be `case 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Return (x) is in else condition of the pop function.
if top==-1 then it will through an error